# When using pgfplots, I receive an error of " Missing { inserted." when using the fillbetween package. Why does this error show up?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I've been using pgfplots to generate images in my homework for a modelling course.  I've been receiving the error below and I can't seem to locate it in my code.

```
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
Package pgfplots info on input line 73: fill between: found 'clip=true'. Prepar
ing pgfplotsextra instruction with clip path for layer 'pre main'...
Package pgfplots info on input line 75: fill between: activating layered graphi
cs
\pgf@layerbox@axis background=\box60
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis background=\box61
\pgf@layerbox@axis grid=\box62
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis grid=\box63
\pgf@layerbox@axis ticks=\box64
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis ticks=\box65
\pgf@layerbox@axis lines=\box66
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis lines=\box67
\pgf@layerbox@axis tick labels=\box68
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis tick labels=\box69
\pgf@layerbox@pre main=\box70
\pgf@layerboxsaved@pre main=\box71
\pgf@layerbox@axis descriptions=\box72
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis descriptions=\box73
\pgf@layerbox@axis foreground=\box74
\pgf@layerboxsaved@axis foreground=\box75
Package pgfplots info on input line 75: Setting layers 'axis background,axis gr
id,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,pre main,main,axis descriptions,axis 
foreground'...
./untitled.tex:75: Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   $
l.75 \end{axis}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

./untitled.tex:75: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.75 \end{axis}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Here is my MWE which generates the error.  My plots turn out fine, but I'm unhappy with compilation errors.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,parskip=half*,oneside,paper=letter]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperindex,setpagesize=false,pdfstartview=Fit]{hyperref}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1.25in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,calc,patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Gill Sans Italic}]{Minion Pro}

\ifpdf\usepackage[linkcolor=blue,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 1},hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}\fi


\newcommand*{\E}{\mathbbm{e}}




\pgfplotstableread{
S_t R_t+2   R^  R^+ R^- Resid   R_t+2   t
694.5250866 2189.100077 1923.359077 2328.022827 1923.77735  2052.424701 2395.342679 2480.683342
1413.385962 5890.33904  3777.200816 4564.31122  3778.015365 3951.711315 4704.10878  4391.013507
1484.115908 5609.424882 3952.352559 4775.181068 3953.204171 4127.583746 4922.241967 3749.410756
1573.08642  8365.224824 4170.86977  5038.154433 4171.767526 4346.195106 5194.382312 5917.141295
1701.821077 9425.686222 4483.516634 5414.201194 4484.480224 4657.459338 5583.7513   8990.504917
}{\conf}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,baseline]
\begin{axis}[align=center,
xlabel={Year},
legend cell align=right,
legend pos = outer north east,
%legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north,draw=none},
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}]
\makeatletter
\addplot table [x=t,y=R_t+2] {\conf};
\addlegendentry{Residuals for $\ln(R)$ vs $\ln(R)^{\wedge}$}
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=1.75,
%align=center,
title={Mean-unbiased estimate\\ with 95\% confidence interval},
xlabel={Year},
legend cell align=right,
legend pos = outer north east,
%legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north,draw=none},
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}]
\addplot table [x=S_t,y={R^}] {\conf};
\addlegendentry{Predicted $R^$};
\addplot table [x=S_t,y={R_t+2}, only marks] {\conf};
\addlegendentry {Actual $R$};
\addplot [name path = top] table [y={R^+}, x=S_t] {\conf} \closedcycle;
\addplot [name path = bottom] table [y={R^-}, x=S_t] {\conf} \closedcycle;
\addplot+ fill between [of=top and bottom, every segment no 0/.style={pattern color = blue, opacity=.35}];
%\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, reduce the example to a minimal one that still shows the issue. Note though that `Predicted $R^$` has a syntax error, and perhaps you want `R^{\wedge}`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was certain it was some silly error like that!!  I was thinking of it as R hat, not the typeset version which properly is R^{\wedge}   Again,  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `R^` can be used as the header for the table in `\pgfplotstableread`, it is not legal in a TeX formula; your line

```
\addlegendentry{Predicted $R^$};
```

has the (TeX side) syntax error that causes the `Missing { inserted` error.

When TeX finds `^` in math mode, it wants to see after it either a token that can be used for a superscript or a left brace.<sup>1</sup> In this case the token after `^` is `$` which is surely not valid. Thus TeX enters error recovery and adds a `{` just to realize that the following token is `$`, so it will try inserting the missing `}` finding itself in sync again.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The left brace can be explicit (`{`) or implicit (`\bgroup`).</sub>